# Two BFS produce the same set of edges

Tags: algorithm, graph, breadth-first-search

Under what kind of constraints, will two BFS (could start from different vertex) on a simple undirected graph produce the same set of edges?

Answer (score 1):

If the graph is a **[minimum spanning tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree)**, then it will produce all the edges in the breadth-first search which can start from any vertex.

**Reason:**

In BFS, all nodes are going to be visited.

The minimum spanning tree contains a minimal number of edges to connect all the nodes. So, the BFS traversal will traverse all the edges in order to visit all the nodes.

So, all the edges of the graph are in the set. That means if you start BFS from any vertex, all the edges are going to be included in the set. Thus, the same set of edges for any node.

Comment: The graph just needs to be a tree. 'Minimum spanning' is unnecessary.

Comment: @Dave Well I think, a tree itself is a minimum spanning tree. but suppose in a graph all nodes are not connected, then MST is a good choice.

Comment: All trees are MSTs; I'm just saying that it's confusing to specify MST when that property has nothing to do with the question being asked.

Comment: @Dave I agree. Actually, I am thinking in terms of a disconnected graph.

Answer (score 1):

Say you run BFS on graph G with starting vertex v (BFS(G, v)) and there is some edge e = (u,w) that isn't traversed. Running BFS(G, u) guarantees that (u,w) is traversed. Thus BFS will only produce a unique set of edges when it produces all edges. I.e. in acyclic graphs.

Comment: But in a tree(a type of graph), bfs from any node will result in the same set of edges.

Comment: @YashShah 'tree' == 'connected acyclic graph'